# Correlation issue in jmeter:The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jmeter, performance-testing

Am trying to generate performance test script in jmeter.

Here one of the page requires `__RequestVerificationToken` as one field which need to be generated from previous page. We have used regular expression extractor to capture the token and passed the same in subsequent request. In the view result tree, I can see the request verification token in appropriate but we are getting  an error

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Here is the regular expression extractor we used.
[image]

Here in the result tree, the request send with token
[image]

Here is the request id which passed through cookie. which will different from previous request. this system genearted.[image]

Please help us, we stuck in this for last two weeks

Following error is thrown in our application,

```
System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
     at abc.def.Web.Filters.ApplicationHandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at abc.def.Web.Base.BaseController.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: could you solve the problem? I am in same trouble

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the pictures it appears that somewhere somehow your extraction fails or you're using hard-coded value instead of extracted one. I would recommend double checking the extracted value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination and ensuring you're using `${RequestVerificationToken}` in the HTTP Request.

---

Also if the variable comes as a [HTTP Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) you can get it directly from the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) like:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
3. Refer the cookie value as `${COOKIE____RequestVerificationToken}` where required.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...actually the request toke id is not hard coded one ..it is taking from previous response itself...